# Does Oracle allow cross schema views?

Tags: sql, oracle, view, schema, oracle11g

In MySQL, I can create a view which points to a table in another schema.  Does Oracle 11g allow this?

Comment: I don't know Oracle, but I'm guessing someone is going to ask what version :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As long as the current account (the one with the view) has appropriate privilege(s) granted in the other schema, things will be fine:

```
GRANT SELECT ON other_schema.table TO user;
```

Comment: Does the cross schema view work if the select permisions are granted to a role that user is a member of? I know stored procedures can only look at tables where the user has permisions granted directly, not through a role.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but your user must have permissions on both schemas.

see: http://itknowledgeexchange.techtarget.com/itanswers/oracle-cross-schema-view/

Answer (score 0):

You might create synonyms for objects in different schemas as well, thus omitting the foreign schema names in your views.

Comment: Beware of synonyms! (Ask Tom ;-)